# How can I create a new line in JTextField to type in?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, multiline

I want to make a Swing program that writes updates on what you have done. It writes all the information on an uneditable `JTextField`.

For example:

```
You have changed the text to BLUE.
You have changed the text to RED.
```

The problem is that I can't make the two lines separate.

What I get is this:

```
You have changed the text to BLUE. You have changed the text to RED.
```

What I've tried is this: (This does not work)

```
TF_BetInfo.setText(TF_BetInfo.getText() + "\nYou have changed the text to BLUE.");
TF_BetInfo.setText(TF_BetInfo.getText() + "\nYou have changed the text to RED.");
```

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: So you mean I should write "TF_betInfo" or change the "TF"? Please write the errors.

Comment: Well the `TF` presumably means text field, and it is considered best not to include the type of control in the name.  Where I find that unworkable is if you need to name (for example) both a label and a field of the same name, then I might use `variableLabel` and `variableField`.  Since the information is `BetInfo` I'd move that to the front, and drop the case of `Bet` to `bet`.  So it would be `betInfoField` for the text field or text area, and `betInfoLabel` for the `JLabel` that describes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't have multiple lines with JTextField , you can use JTextArea for that purpose , and the code wouldn't be much different too , you can still use the same code or you can just

```
TF_BetInfo.append("\nyou have ...... ");
```

where TF_Betinfo is a JTextArea rather than a JTextField .

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `JTextField` for this. `JTextField` is sinle-line edit control. That is why you got all your output in one line.

If you want several lines to be printed in edit use [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html). In your case you can use [`jTextArea.append(string)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append-java.lang.String-) (note: `jTextArea` is an object of class `JTextArea`, and `string` is an object of class `String`).

Answer (score 0):

You **can't actually use several lines in a JTextField**, but what you can do, is using a **JTextArea** of the wanted size, and then use the following:

```
yourJTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
```

This will **automatically detect** when the JTextArea needs to use another line and add it, pretty cool, useful and you only need one code line to do it.

JTextArea is more flexible but if you really want flexibility read about **JTextPane** or **JEditorPane**, you can show URLS, internet pages and everything that comes to your mind.